# Where to find FAQ or documents for google swiffy

Tags: google-swiffy

I have been googling and could not find the documentation of google swiffy. The site https://developers.google.com/swiffy/ does not show much details on it.

I tried to debug the converted swf to html in ie and found these two methods. Stage.setFlashVars and Stage.SetSwfUrl.  I just need to know details on how to use these.

Thanks.

Best regards
Nai

Comment: This [help/on-topic] page says pretty clearly: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: I apologize for this. I cant find a delete function to remove this. Thank you